# StaticResource in app.xaml not found in Resource Dictionary referenced from app.xaml

Tags: .net, wpf, staticresource

I've got a situation where I'm attempting to resolve visual components in a data template referenced in a resource dictionary, referring to a static resource of the `app.xaml` markup, see example below.

`App.xaml`

```
<Application 
    x:Class="App" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"      
    xmlns:composition="clr-namespace:Composition"
    ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <composition:ApplicationContainer x:Key="ApplicationContainer"/>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary
Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Composition/DataTemplates.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

`Composition/DataTemplates.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:projectvm="clr-namespace:ViewModels.ProjectManagement"
                    xmlns:unity="clr-namespace:Extensions">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type projectvm:ProjectDocument}">
        <ContentControl>
            <!-- Custom Extension that resolves a component from
            the composition container -->
            <unity:Resolve Container="{StaticResource ApplicationContainer}"
  TargetType="{x:Type projectvm:ProjectDocument}" ContractName="ProjectDocument"/>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The error is just above. The unity: Resolve line cannot locate the `ApplicationContainer` Static Resource. And I don't understand why.

Comment: It's a runtime error.  I'm thinking it might have to do with having a staticresource on a markup extension but idk.

Comment: Did that, got an error about using dynamic resource on a non dependency object.

Comment: Have you tried moving the "ApplicationContainer" resource from App.xaml into DataTemplates.xaml (above the ProjectDocument DataTemplate)?

Comment: Have you determined a solution or workaround for this? Just ran into this issue.

Comment: [This forum Q&A](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31872/application-resources-staticresource-not-found-for-key) might be helpful.